# Display the ajax data on the same page in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel-5.1

I am working in laravel 5.1. I have three pages in routes **Home,show,short**.
I also have blade file for home and short routes

I have a form on home page .After submit the button on home page I want that 
(1). the data will be save at the database via post request which code has been written in a method **postdata()** which routes is **show.**.

(2). I want to display the results based on the inserted data after doing query from database which code has written in **showdata()** method of **short** route .

I want all that happen after clicking the submit button without refreshing the page.but my problem is that i have two routes and in url of ajax method how can i give two url. please suggest me the better and efficient way to do that.

Comment: Yes you can do it using ajax , but what you have tried to get your job done post that part of code.

Comment: How can i post the data and get value from the db and display on the same page because for posting data and displaying data i have two function with two routes that means I have two page so in url property withing ajax function how can i mention two pages.

Comment: have you tried to use ajax to request the data you want ?

Comment: please check my website http://ucut.herokuapp.com/ i am trying to display the result on the homepage not on the short page

Comment: then you need to send a ajax request something like `$(document).ready(function(){
 $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/lara_todo/public/lists", function(response){}` I did something like this but with laravel 4.2 before 10 months, now I am not working on laravel but this was the code part I used to get my job done.